# How to get all http Response in Angular Interceptor when API responds error

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

There is a problem with getting the full http headers on handling error response.

**Problem foreword in facts:**

Api adds a **new header parameter** when smth wrong happens(in our case it's `X-Message`), or when everything is ok but some additional message exists with useful details.

```ruby
response.headers['X-Message'] = 'A user has no permissions to approve smth'

response.headers['X-Message'] = 'You've approved smth successfully, but...'
```

On the client side(Angular app), it's handled by interceptor:

```typescript
return next.handle(request)
    .pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                this.notificationHandler.handle(event);
            }
            return event;
        }), 

    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        /*
        Problem is here!!!
        I need to get the response headers to
        read 'X-Message', but it's unavailable.
        */

        this.notificationHandler.handle(error);
        return throwError(error);
    });
```

**Where is the problem?**
When `response.status` is `200` everything is OK. I can get and show the appropriate header field. BUT When **status is `400` or more the needed header is unavailable**

Have you had some kind of problems when the full list of headers are needed in ``catchError``` handle?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the http headers of the request, you have access to it via the [HttpErrorResponse class](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse).

As you can se via the documentation, you can call:

```js
return next.handle(request)
    .pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => { .... }), 
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        // Access is given by:
        console.log(error.headers.get('X-Message'));
        this.notificationHandler.handle(error);
        return throwError(error);
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Angular has a built in error handler class. That catch all the errors.
https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

Comment: This is not a good approach since it will impact all errors, not just those of `HttpClient` requests.